# R ggplot2 facet wrap dot plot reorder each

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet

I have the following graph using the public mtcars dataset. I first converted to a tibble and kept the car information as a column I could use.

```
mtcars <- as_tibble(mtcars, rownames = 'car')

ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg, y = reorder(car, mpg))) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

You can see that I reordered the y axis cars based on the value of mpg.

I also have a long dataframe:

```
mtcars_numeric <- mtcars %>%
  dplyr::select(car, mpg, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec) 

mtcars_long_numeric_with_mpg <- pivot_longer(mtcars_numeric, names_to = 'names', values_to = 'values', 2:7)

ggplot(mtcars_long_numeric_with_mpg, aes(x = values, y = reorder(car, values))) +
  geom_point() + facet_wrap(~names, scales = 'free_x')+
theme(text = element_text(size=6))
```

How can I put each car in order of the value when all the facets are different? I'm looking to rearrange the y axis labels to make the curve for each facet similar to the first graph.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be achieved via `reorder_within` + `scale_y_reordered` from the `tidytext` package like so:

1. Reorder you y axis variable by values within facets via `reorder_within`
2. Use `scale_y_reordered`
3. Set the scales free for your y-axis too.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidytext)

mtcars2 <- as_tibble(mtcars, rownames = 'car')

mtcars_long_numeric_with_mpg <- mtcars2 %>%
  select(car, mpg, disp, hp, drat, wt, qsec) %>% 
  pivot_longer(names_to = 'names', values_to = 'values', 2:7) %>% 
  mutate(car = tidytext::reorder_within(car, values, names))

ggplot(mtcars_long_numeric_with_mpg, aes(x = values, y = reorder(car, values))) +
  geom_point() + 
  tidytext::scale_y_reordered() +
  facet_wrap(~names, scales = 'free')+
  theme(text = element_text(size=6))
```

[image]

Comment: this is a great answer I'm going to have to learn about tidytext